# in sqlalchemy, how can I import existing table having foreign key on the other table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two Tables as bellow:

table `series`:

```
+-------------+
| Field       |
+-------------+
| series_id   |
| title       |
+-------------+
```

table `season`:

```
+-------------+
| Field       |
+-------------+
| season_id   |
| title       |
| version     |
| duration    |
| series_id   |
+-------------+
```

In `season`, `series_id` as foreign key referees from `series(series_id)`

Now I want load these two table via sqlalchemy. Is that possible to build a one-to-many relationship between these two tables so that I can access all seasons object of one series?

Comment: The short answer is yes, it is possible. You can either use [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) and work with core objects (`Table`s etc.), or [automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) to build ORM models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SQLAlchemy automatically create relationships from a database schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398329/can-sqlalchemy-automatically-create-relationships-from-a-database-schema)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! The `series_id` field of the `season` table will be a foreign key to the `series` table. To get all seasons of a particular series, you will query the 'season' table for all entries which have a particular series_id.

Look at this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying